# Problems executing selenium on ubuntu server

Tags: java, testing

I am trying to execute `Selenium` on `Ubuntu Server` but I have always problem with driver version. I don't know more options to check it so I am here to try to solve this.

**First the environment:**

> Maven : Apache Maven 3.3.9
>   Java : 1.8
>   Chrome : Google Chrome 59.0.3071.115
>   Chrome driver :  ChromeDriver 2.30.477691

When I try to execute `mvn clean test`, it returns this **ERROR**:

> Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'ubuntu-2gb-lon1-01', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-81-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
>   Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

**The simple java code is this:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://google.es");
driver.quit();
```

Could anyone help to me to install a Chrome driver version to solve this?
I think that I am not doing this correctly.

Regards!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "**Driver Path**");

Here you have to pass the path where your driver is located in your disk.